# Night Shader effects Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vuforia

What i'm trying to do is, with and augmented reality app with vuforia, i want to obscure the whole scene to give a "night effect"(The real camera texture has to be obscure too).I been trying this for a couple days now.

I searched for it and only found help in night vision effects, wich give me the idea on how to approach this problem.I'm been trying it with a shader linked to the camera.

How can i do a night effect(Just obscure the whole scene, it would be better if i could obscure only desired objects) with a shader?

Any other idea on how to do this would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious approach would be to use a dark-colored and thick fog. And turn the lights down, of course. Beyond that, your query is a bit vague. But try the fog.